# `who` or `finger` command not showing connected users (Bash on Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, bash, unix

I have installed Bash on Windows 10 and while learning Unix I have found out that the commands `who` and `finger` don't show logged in users.

When I type `who` in Bash it just shows nothing… Also, when I type `finger` it shows:

> No one logged on

(but I think it should show at least my current logged user).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You might test *finger* at the Windows CMD prompt, to see if it shows your session there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/573) according to Microsft's GitHub BashOnWindows.  Since Bash on Windows is in beta, expect to find things that dont work properly.